# Could someone provide a simple example of getting DocumentProperties in Office.js?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

How do I get the author or title of a Word document using Office.js (1.3)?

I read the documentation on [documentProperties](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/documentproperties) but I need an example to get the syntax right.

Help appreciated!

Comment: maybe this can help a bit https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/master/samples/word/07-custom-properties/get-built-in-properties.yaml

Answer (score 5):

The following code snippet gets the author and title of the document and writes those property values to the console.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
  var document = context.document;
  document.properties.load("author, title");
  
  return context.sync()
    .then(function () {
      console.log("The author of this document is " + document.properties.author + " and the title is '" + document.properties.title + "'");
    });
});
```

Note that with the Office.js APIs, you must call the `load()` method on an object to explicitly load the property value before you'll be able to read it. (You can find information about the `load()` method in the [same article you linked to in your question](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/documentproperties).)

Comment: For some reason when I try to run this code, the document.properties is always undefined. I am using Office 2016 and VS2017. Do you guys know this issue?